# Type error in LWC cannot read properties of null - the log is showing the data

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, javascript-debugging

I have a LWC that I am debugging(did not write it myself). Its showing 'Type error in LWC cannot read properties of null' yet when i print to the console i can see the data. What else could be the issue?

[image: Error]

Edited: The template code ..

```
  <template for:each={data} for:item="row">
                <tr key={row.ActiveOpportunity.Id}>
                    <th scope="col" class="slds-truncate">
                        <div>
                            <template if:true={row}>
                                <lightning-formatted-url value={row.AccountUrl} label={row.ActiveAccount.Name}>
                                </lightning-formatted-url>
                           </template>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                    <th scope="col" class="slds-truncate">
                        <div>
                            <template if:true={row}>
                            <lightning-formatted-url value={row.OpportunityUrl} label={row.ActiveOpportunity.Name}>
                            </lightning-formatted-url>
                        </template>
```

...

[image]

The row.ActiveOpportunity.Name is working okay but the row.ActiveAccount.Name is throwing an error.

The log output which I pasted on a json formatter..

What else should I check?

Thanks!

Edited: Array declaration

```
const columns = [
{ 
    label: 'Client', 
    fieldName: 'AccountUrl',
    type: 'url',
    sortable: true,
    hideDefaultActions: true,
    typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'ActiveAccount.Name'},
    }
},
{ 
    label: 'Name', 
    fieldName: 'OpportunityUrl',
    type: 'url',
    sortable: true,
    hideDefaultActions: true,
    typeAttributes: {
        label: { fieldName: 'ActiveOpportunity.Name'},
    },
    cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' }
},
```

Edited: JS code..

```
connectedCallback() {
    load()
    .then(result => {
        this.data = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log('Data found '+ JSON.stringify( this.data));
    })
```

Output..

```
Data found [{"ScheduledInterviewTotal":0,"ScheduledClientInterviewTotal":0,"OpportunityUrl":"/lightning/r/Opportunity/0066s0000059pFQAAY/view","InterviewTotal":0,"HealthNumericalValue":0,"Health":"green","ClientInterviewTotal":0,"ActiveOpportunity":{"attributes":{"type":"Opportunity","url":"/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Opportunity/0066s0000059pFQAAY"},"Id":"0066s0000059pFQAAY","Name":"Search Test","RecordTypeId":"0125A000001ReU6QAK","AccountId":"0015A00002GCSXgQAP","RecordType":{"attributes":{"type":"RecordType","url":"/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/RecordType/0125A000001ReU6QAK"},"Name":"C","Id":"0125A000001ReU6QAK"},"Account":{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Account/0015A00002GCSXgQAP"},"Name":"Bravolta","Id":"0015A00002GCSXgQAP"}},"ActiveAccount":{"attributes":{"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v53.0/sobjects/Account/0015A00002GCSXgQAP"},"Name":"Bravolta","Id":"0015A00002GCSXgQAP"},"AccountUrl":"/lightning/r/Account/0015A00002GCSXgQAP/view"},
```

[image]

Comment: I have added the code snippet.

Comment: thanks, now, as per your array of data, it's not clear how it is structured, can you also replace the screenshot with the actual array of objects you have?

Comment: I have added the column info in the js. is that what you meant?

Comment: no, should be what you are assigning to your `data` property, on which you are iterating over in your template

Comment: I have added the js code where the data property is being assigned

Comment: shown the output above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, it might be possible that in some instances, your ActiveAccount node might be missing a Name property. However, I can't confirm.

As a best practice, you don't want to access nested properties without checking if they are null or undefined, otherwise, you will run into these types of issues.

In order to ensure this does not happen, add a `<template if:true={row.ActiveAccount}>`
to make sure that there is one before attempting to access one of its properties.

Comment: Oh my gosh! That worked! Thank you so  much!